# Webdriverio 5: how to get the latest DOM objects

Tags: typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am currently working on REact based CMS application. Its a multiple carousel based Form. I am trying to locate an element and it fails to locate in the webdriverio implementation. But the same xpath works perfectly well when I tried it manually. I reckon webdirverio is still retaining the old DOM objects from the initial page loa and not getting the latest ones at the time of execution. I can not refresh the page as it will take the user journey back to step 1 . Could you let me know how to get the updated DOM objects in webdriverio.

> element ("//div[@id="question"]//label[.="preferred option"]")
>   still not displayed after 3000ms

Answer (score 0):

Try using waitForExist. Wait untill your locator exist in the DOM.

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForExist.html

```
Let webelm = await browser.$('your locator');
webelm.waitForExist();
```

Later your can proceed with your tests on the element.

For example : click function should be like

```
async click(element,time) {
        const elem = await browser.$(element);
        await elem.waitForExist(time);
        await elem.isDisplayed(time);
        await elem.click();
    }
```

Comment: element ("//div[@id="question"]//label[.="preferred option"]") still not existing after 3000ms

Comment: Thanks for the response Bharath. But unfortunately it fails with the above error message. The trouble is that the element is available and visible. But since the wdio retains the very first pagesource it could not locate it, could not use reloadSession or refresh as that sets the form back to step 1.

Comment: Maybe it requires to wait a little bit more time. Did you try adding webelm.waitForExist(10000)?

Comment: 3000ms is sufficient. I can see the dropdown with the expected values. Just want to understand how to refersh the "$" driver value in webdriverio to have the latest DOM in it

Comment: http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls. Your application is something similar to this?

Comment: I have edited the answer. This handles all dynamic elements.

Comment: <label for="option-0-13" data-open="exampleModal1" class="option-0-13-modal">between ~0~</label>

The element would look this ~0~ when the website is loaded for the first time. 
But the more I come closed to this particular steps, then it will update the tilda value with the value. Hence it would look like "between 500 and 1000£

When I try to manually test the element by passing the final expected test step's DOM , it is failing.  
Thanks for support, but your updated answer is not helping much in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute exact scenario manually which is there in automation.If you are not getting exact expected DOM then it will be step execution issue.
There no concept like latest DOM

Comment: Updated the element information in the below answer Yogesh. That will provide more sense on what I meant by latest.